# how to generate one 2D array whose elements are uniformly random numbers at axis=0, and are normal random at axis=1

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to generate a two-dimensional array, such as (10000, 1024) using numpy or scipy. I hope that elements of each row of this array satisfy normal distribution. However, elements of each column are uniformly random numbers.

I have no idea how to achieve this goal. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this mean that each element is sampled from both normal and uniform distribution at the same time?

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem Yes

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but it seems impossible. Suppose that you could generate `N` independent copies of such an array, then plot the distribution of the element in position `[1,1]`. It would have to be both a bell curve and a rectangle simultaneously.

Comment: If you mean a distribution P_XY such that the marginalization are a Normal and a Uniform then one way of doing it is assuming independence between X and Y so that P_XY(x,y) = P_X(x)*P_Y(y). However that is a probability table, not a random array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have a "perfectly" uniform distribution on columns with a normal distribution on rows (if you're talking about a random variates matrix).

But if the scales (standard deviations) are not too wide you can combine `sps.norm` and `sps.uniform` so that the locations (means) and scales can be enough uniformly distributed by row.

For example

```
# imports
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as sps
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# define rows and columns
# define rows and columns
rows = 10000
cols = 1024
# generate random samples
matrix = sps.norm(
    # uniformly distributed locations
    loc=sps.uniform(0, 200).rvs(rows).reshape(-1, 1),
    # uniformly distributed scales
    scale=sps.uniform(1, 5).rvs(rows).reshape(-1, 1),
).rvs((rows, cols))
```

You can verify that all rows are normally distributed

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 4, figsize=(15, 8))
# take some random test rows
test_rows = np.random.choice(rows, size=8)
# plot rows histplots
for i, row in enumerate(test_rows):
    sns.histplot(matrix[row,:].ravel(), ax=ax.flat[i])
    ax.flat[i].set(
        ylabel=None,
        title=f'row {row}'
    )
```

[image]

and columns are fairly similar to a uniform distribution

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 4, figsize=(15, 8))
# take some random test columns
test_cols = np.random.choice(cols, size=8)
# plot columns histplots
for i, col in enumerate(test_cols):
    sns.histplot(matrix[:,col].ravel(), ax=ax.flat[i])
    ax.flat[i].set(
        ylabel=None,
        title=f'column {col}'
    )
```

[image]

But the higher the standard deviations are, the more columns will deviate from the uniform distribution towards the normal distribution themselves.